# Aurelia http.get not working with Firefox

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I am using the aurelia http.get and it works with IE and Chrome but Firefox throws an exception 'SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data'.

When I console.log the return in Firefox it has tags on it as such,

```
 <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
    [{"ID":1,"Name":"Bob",...}]
 </string>
```

This is straight from the API call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer in the Aurelia Gitter. The issue was that Firefox defaults http.get request to xml and you have to configure the httpClient to expressly ask for json.

```
httpClient.configure(config => {
    config.withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
});
```

That solved my issue.  Not sure why Firefox defaults to XML. The controller even said to JsonConvert.Seralize(content) on return but Firefox didn't care.  IE and Chrome work fine.  Thanks @apawsey for helping me understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Dont have enough rep to comment. It would help if you posted ur http.get code. U are obviously getting your data but the format seems wrong (at least for Firefox). I suggest u read on the docs and find how to set the type of data being sent in the http call. I think other browsers figure that out for themselves but Firefox seems to be lost

Comment: Check first comment by chovy here: https://github.com/aurelia/http-client/issues/39

Comment: IE format is correct actually, it's Firefox that has this format.  I changed the headers as requested but still the same result.  Is there a way to convert the return to JSON?  I looked at the MIME Type and it does say XML.

Comment: Ok. Do u have Fiddler installed? I want to see the headers being sent out. If u check here https://www.sencha.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-147223.html   someone had a similar problem. Chrome and IE were fine but Firefox was getting XML instead of json.

Comment: Btw please post ur http.get code. I want to see hoe u set the headers. If specifying it in the configuration did not help u can use an interceptor to see if that works

Comment: Found the answer and posted the solution.